# Nuxt.js / Vuex - using Namespace modules in mapActions helper, [vuex] unknown action type: FETCH_LABEL

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I am trying to map an action to a component using `mapActions` helper from vuex. Here is my labels.js vuex module:

```
export const FETCH_LABELS = 'FETCH_LABELS'
export const FETCH_LABEL = 'FETCH_LABEL'

const state = () => ({
  labels: [
    { name: 'Mord Records', slug: 'mord', image: '/images/labels/mord.jpg'},
    { name: 'Subsist Records', slug: 'subsist', image: '/images/labels/subsist.jpg'},
    { name: 'Drumcode Records', slug: 'drumcode', image: '/images/labels/drumcode.png'},
  ],
  label: {} // null
})

const mutations = {
  FETCH_LABEL: (state, { label }) => {
    state.label = label
  },
}

const actions = {
  fetchLabel({commit}, slug) {
    
    let label = state.labels.filter((slug, index) => {
      return slug == state.labels[index]
    })

    commit(FETCH_LABEL, { label })
  },
}

const getters = {
  labels: state => {
    return state.labels
  },

  label: (state, slug) => {
  }
}

export default {
  state,
  mutations,
  actions,
  getters
}
```

Here is my component _slug.vue page where I want to map the fetchLabel action:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">

        <div class="section">
            <div class="box">
                <h1>{{ $route.params.slug }}</h1>
            </div>
         
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from "vuex";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      title: this.$route.params.slug
    };
  },
  computed: {
    // Research
    // labels() {
    //   return this.$store
    // }

    ...mapGetters({
      labels: "modules/labels/labels"
    })
  },
  components: {},
  methods: {
    ...mapActions({
      fetchLabel: 'FETCH_LABEL' // map `this.add()` to `this.$store.dispatch('increment')`
    })
  },
  created() {
    console.log('created')
    this.fetchLabel(this.$route.params.slug)
  },
  head() {
    return {
      title: this.title
    }
  },
  layout: "app",
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

However inside the `created()` lifecycle hook at `this.fetchLabel(this.$route.params.slug)` it throws the following error in the console:

> [vuex] unknown action type: FETCH_LABEL

What am I missing or doing wrong? Please help me solve this.

Answer (score 6):

Note that in Nuxt.js:

Modules: **every .js** file inside the store directory is transformed as a namespaced module (index being the root module).

You are using:

> Here is my labels.js vuex module:

with labels.js as you stated above so you'll need to access everything as namespaced modules so your mapAction helper should be like as such:

```
methods: {
  ...mapActions({
    nameOfMethod: 'namespace/actionName'
  })
}
```

So you would have this:

```
...mapActions({
  fetchLabel: 'labels/fetchLabel'
})
```

You could also clean it up by doing so for when you'd like to retain the name of your action as your method name.

```
...mapActions('namespace', ['actionName']),
...
```

So you would have this:

```
...mapActions('labels', ['fetchLabel']),
...
```

In both cases the computed prop should work without a problem.

Answer (score 3):

Your action name is `fetchLabel` and not `FETCH_LABEL` (which is a mutation). In `mapActions` change to

```
methods: {
  ...mapActions({
     fetchLabel
  })
},
```

Comment: I have tried this approach already. It says "fetchLabel is not defined" and I couldn't do it.

Comment: could it be fetchLabel: 'modules/labels/fetchLabel'? I think I managed to get it working like this? However is this usual for nuxt.js?

Comment: Since nuxt treats all .js files in the store directory as namespaces fetchLabel: 'labels/fetchLabel' will be the right way and norm.